# Wordpress Nav--Top level expands with subnav dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I've styled a Wordpress navigation bar that uses JQuery to show the subnav when you roll over, however it expands the whole div to fit the subnav inside and all the top-layer nav goes all "skiwumpus" when the sub-nav comes in.

I can't figure out how to resolve.

The URL is http://www.studio-element.com/spyglass

Also, "Products" has a subnav.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I use the follwoing style for some of my web sites:

```
#menu-main-menu {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-top: 43px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: auto;
}

#menu-main-menu ul.sub-menu {
    min-width: 130px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wanting to use JQuery so I would have a nice animated open.